# Post data to page and get resulting data (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm working with the blackbaud API and it says I need to send post data to a url to receive the data I want in XML.

Reference: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/helpfiles/FAFAPI/default.htm

I wasn't too sure how to do this so I used jQuery's POST method and got the cross domain error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Here is the code I used to send the request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post("https://www.kintera.org/api/Authentication/Login.ashx?accountid=xxxxx",
        {username: "xxxxxx", password:"xxxxxxx"},function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
})
```

Can anyone here lead me in the right direction? When I do a simple php post to the page the xml result is displayed, I just don't know how I can get that information for my own use. Advice?

**The biggest problem I'm having is that cross-domain error**

EDIT:
Figured it out. For anyone who has the same problem here was my solution using curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.kintera.org/api/Authentication/Login.ashx?accountid=xxxxxxx");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('username' => $username,'password' => $password)));

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross ajax domain by using proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584262/cross-ajax-domain-by-using-proxy)

Comment: Try adding `callback=?` in url

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a cross domain error :/

Comment: Post to your server, allow your server to do the login, pass back whatever is necessary.

Comment: Do you think you can elaborate a little on how this is done? How do I do this with the server? Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

XHR (aka. Ajax) calls are not allowed to be cross-domain for [security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). But there's a format [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to deal with this issue. It basically places your JSON data in a method name, which can be evaluated as callback and feed the data inside your application.

When using jQuery you might want to take a look at [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get you started.